# P&T Contact Form v1 adding code for 'beforeSend'

Tags: plugin-contactform

Very new to Craft, so can someone please tell me what class/file I'd add the 'The beforeSend event' code, as I'd like to filter out some spam?

The documentation https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/hooks-and-events.html#hooks says that the new event listener should be added to the plugins 'init' function, but there isn't one.

many thanks

Comment: Which version of Craft do you use? 2 or 3. Do you look to any another plugin and copy function structure?

Comment: The version is 2.6.3017, I don't know where to put the call to the event code or where the event code should go, I could hack it but I would like to know the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way is little bit longer.

Firstly, you need your own plugin, you can generate skeleton here: https://pluginfactory.io/ It's better than rewrite someone else's, because you can't update it after you add a code.

Secondly, you add your beforeSend Event to Plugin class by add it to init function - the function will be generated in step one - it is in the YourNamePlugin php file in root.

If you start a new project, it is better to work in Craft 3.